# Building OpenMP's preprocessor's directive based on variadic function's input

Tags: c++, boost, openmp, preprocessor, variadic

The function takes a variadic list of dependencies to delegate to OpenMP's preprocessor's directive. The variadic list is known at compile-time. It is expanded at runtime which doesn't help at preprocessing stage. Any suggestions/solutions of how this can be done? An example of what I want to achieve is as follows:

```
void dependencies(int count, ...) {  
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    int* arr[count];    // an array of pointers to the dependencies
    int start[count];   // starting element of the array
    int end[count];     // ending element of the array 
    int direction[count];   // direction of dependency
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        arr[i] = va_arg(args, int*);
        start[i] = va_arg(args, int);
        end[i]   = va_arg(args, int);
        direction[i] = va_arg(args, int);
    }
    va_end(args);

// repeat count number of times while respecting the input params  
#pragma omp task depend(direction_:arr_[start_:end_]) 

}
// for example 
int a[3];
int b[5];
dependencies(2, a, 0, 3, inout, b, 0, 5, out);

// should yield 
#pragma omp task depend(inout:a[0:3]) depend(out:b[0:5])
```

p.s. I am adding Boost to the list of tags because I believe something can be done with the Boost Preprocessor functionality. I couldn't find a useful reference for that.